# Extjs ComponentQuery query selector

Tags: extjs

I have 3 query statments where I query for 3 elements and mask them:

```
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('Notepanel')[0].mask()
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=bannerTopP]')[0].mask();
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=bannerBottomP]')[0].mask()
```

Is there a way to combine all of these and make it into a single statement in the `query` to mask all 3?

Comment: Mask on parent component/div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('Notepanel, [itemId=bannerTopP], [itemId=bannerBottomP]').forEach(function(cmp){ cmp.mask(); })
```